# An error occurred while saving the customer , in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting this error please help me anyone if know.
An error occurred while saving the customer

in back end i edit the customer and click on save button or save and continue edit then showing this error.

after i have some code comment in this file CustomerController.php

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->_getSession()->addException($e, Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('An error occurred while saving the customer.'));
    $this->_getSession()->setCustomerData($data);
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl('*/customer/edit', array('id'=>$customer->getId())));
    return;
}
```

after get this error.

There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Trace:

> 0 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> 1 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> 2 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> 3 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `eu...', Array)
>
> 4 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `eu...', Array)
>
> 5 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `eu...', Array)
>
> 6 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('euvat_customer_...', Array)
>
> 7 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Pisc_Euvat_Model_Customer_Exclude))
>
> 8 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/local/Pisc/Euvat/Helper/Adminhtml.php(33): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
>
> 9 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/local/Pisc/Euvat/Model/Adminhtml/Observer.php(58): Pisc_Euvat_Helper_Adminhtml->updateCustomer(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer), Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> 10 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Pisc_Euvat_Model_Adminhtml_Observer->eventAdminhtmlCustomerPrepareSave(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> 11 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Pisc_Euvat_Model_Adminhtml_Observer), 'eventAdminhtmlC...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>
> 12 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('adminhtml_custo...', Array)
>
> 13 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(319): Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_custo...', Array)
>
> 14 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->saveAction()
>
> 15 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
>
> 16 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> 17 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> 18 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> 19 /var/www/html/raptor_supplies/index.php(89): Mage::run('default', 'store')
>
> 20 {main}

Answer (score 0):

First repair then optimize the database. Then clear the cache.